# Why doesn't my PS3 screen fit the TV?

Tags: ps3

My PS3 screen seems to not want to fit the TV. I tried messing around with the displays and it doesn't help at all I even put it to 720 yeta with no results.

How can I get it to fit?

Comment: Safezoning maybe? Not sure how you can do it on ps3 though.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? Does it not fill the screen? Is it bigger than the screen?